# Is there a way to automatically detect when MapView is zoomed to a certain level?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I want to display pin annotations on my map, but since I have so many, I only want to display them when the map is sufficiently zoomed in. Is there a way to detect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [this delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204-CH3-SW4) inside your view controller that holds your map view:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{        
    if (mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta < DESIRED_VALUE) 
    {
       //code to alert map view
    }

}
```

To derive `DESIRED_VALUE`, you need to gather values of `longitudeDelta` for multiple zooming experiments. Same function can be used to gather such logs.

Comment: Thanks!

Also, is there a way to display a message that says "Zoom in to view" in the middle of the view?

Comment: There is no 'way' as such except to display it as a label or something. Read docs, search questions on SO and you will find it pretty easy to implement.